# ttest on many columns in Matlab/R

Tags: r, matlab, sas

Does anybody know the examples on how to run paired ttest in Matlab/R/SAS or Python/Java on many columns (I have 1139 variables) in all combinations or selected respective columns in a loop.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

#### MATLAB Solution:

If I understand correctly, you're just looking for a way to feed [`ttest`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ttest.html) with two different columns from your input matrix everytime. You can get all possible combinations of column pairs using [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html):

```
pairs = nchoosek(1:size(X, 2), 2);
```

Now you can iterate over these indices, each time invoking [`ttest`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ttest.html) with a different pair:

```
for idx = transpose(pairs)
    h = ttest(X(:, idx(1)), X(:, idx(2)));

    %// Do something with the result...
end
```